# How to delete true orphaned taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, database

I have a taxonomy vocabulary that contains a large number (5000+) of orphaned taxonomy terms. By *orphaned* I mean that they refer to parent terms that no longer exist, or refer to parents who are themselves orphans (grand-orphans ?). I am **not** talking about unused terms.

I do not see these terms in the Drupal interface as they are no longer connected to the main hierarchy. I can however still see them in the database, and I can open them directly using the tid in the Drupal interface.

I can't bulk delete them using any module because modules get the entire tree of the vocab to delete - and they are no longer part of the tree. I think I will have to delete them manually in the database. 
I can delete the terms from the taxonomy_term_data and taxonomy_term_hierarchy tables:

```
DELETE FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy WHERE parent NOT IN (SELECT tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy) // or something like it
```

Are there any other tables I need to think of though, in order to not end up with a database that's messed up worse than it already is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't advise doing that - taxonomy terms are entities and need to be cleaned up with [`taxonomy_term_delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_delete/7). Otherwise you'll potentially leave a lot of orphaned data in field tables/contrib module tables/etc.

However, if you know your `DELETE` query will get you the correct terms, just convert it to a `SELECT` and you can do things the proper way:

```
$tids = db_query('SELECT tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy WHERE parent NOT IN (SELECT tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy)')->fetchCol();

foreach ($tids as $tid) {
  taxonomy_term_delete($tid);
}
```

Be wary that you don't delete top-level terms that have a parent of `0`, since that record will not appear in your sub-query. It'll probably need a bit more thought, but the above code won't be too far off what you end up using.

Comment: That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The query I ended up using for selecting the orphaned children tid's was the following:

```
SELECT T1.tid
FROM 
taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS T1 INNER JOIN
taxonomy_term_data ON
T1.tid = taxonomy_term_data.tid LEFT JOIN
taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS T2 ON
T1.parent = T2.tid LEFT JOIN
taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS T3 ON
T2.parent = T3.tid LEFT JOIN
taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS T4 ON
T3.parent = T4.tid LEFT JOIN
taxonomy_term_hierarchy AS T5 ON
T4.parent = T5.tid
WHERE 
((T1.parent NOT IN (SELECT tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy) AND T1.parent != 0) OR
(T2.parent NOT IN (SELECT tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy) AND T2.parent != 0) OR
(T3.parent NOT IN (SELECT tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy) AND T3.parent != 0) OR
(T4.parent NOT IN (SELECT tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy) AND T4.parent != 0) OR
(T5.parent NOT IN (SELECT tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy) AND T5.parent != 0)) AND
taxonomy_term_data.vid = 5
```

Because I was sure no hierarchy deeper than 5 levels existed in my list. For deeper hierarchies you would add more joins. Obviously the vid is situation specific as well.