# How to bulk delete empty taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

The website has thousands of unused (empty) taxonomy terms and I want to **bulk** delete them.

With views all empty terms can be listed but it's not possible to delete them via Views (VBO etc).

I saw that taxonomy terms should be cleaned with `taxonomy_term_delete()` in this question: [How to delete true orphaned taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/99039/28275). But I don't know where to use it? **Should I create a block and put the code inside it or a custom module or anything else?**

(I also tried the [Delete Orphaned Terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/delete_orphaned_terms) module but couldn't be sure if it's working properly. I tried it on a dev. site but couldn't check the results.)

Comment: I edit my answer with another solution, take a look ;-)

Comment: finally, do you solve your problem?

Comment: Would you be interested in a **Rules Component** that you might be able to use as an "Operation" in your VBO view?

Comment: Thanks, actually I have already used a "simple" method for this and forgot to share it. I will share the solution soon.

Comment: can you share your solution?

Answer (score 4):

A quick solution:

Go to your folder theme and edit the `node.tpl.php` and put this code at the top of the file:

```
<?php

$query = "
SELECT taxonomy_term_data.tid AS tid
FROM 
{taxonomy_term_data} taxonomy_term_data
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} taxonomy_index ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = taxonomy_index.tid
LEFT JOIN {node} node_taxonomy_index ON taxonomy_index.nid = node_taxonomy_index.nid
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} taxonomy_vocabulary ON taxonomy_term_data.vid = taxonomy_vocabulary.vid
GROUP BY tid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT node_taxonomy_index.nid) = '0'
";

$tids = db_query($query)->fetchCol();

foreach ($tids as $tid) {
  taxonomy_term_delete($tid);
}
dpm($tids);
?>
```

Then go to visit one of your nodes and the code will be triggered.

Take into account that if you don't eliminate the code from the `node.tlp.php` then every time that you access a node the code will be triggered.

**EDIT: I (quickly) created a little module for you. Is not the best solution but I tested it and it works.**

file: **delete_unused_taxonomy_terms.info**

```
name = Delete Unused Taxonomy Terms
description = Delete all unused taxonomy terms
core = 7.x
package = Administration

configure = admin/structure/delete_unused_taxonomy_terms

files[] = delete_unused_taxonomy_terms.module
files[] = delete_unused_taxonomy_terms.admin.inc
```

file: **delete_unused_taxonomy_terms.module**

```
<?php

/**
 * @file delete_unused_taxonomy_terms.module
 */

/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function delete_unused_taxonomy_terms_menu() {
  $items['admin/structure/delete_unused_taxonomy_terms'] = array(
  'title' => 'Delete Unused Taxonomy Terms',
  'description' => 'Delete Unused Taxonomy Terms',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('delete_unused_taxonomy_terms_admin_settings'),
  'access callback' => 'user_access',
  'access arguments' => array('administer taxonomy'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'file' => 'delete_unused_taxonomy_terms.admin.inc',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

File: **delete_unused_taxonomy_terms.admin.inc**

```
<?php
/**
* @file
* Calls results to administration's pages.
*/

/**
* Form constructor for module configuration.
*
*/
function delete_unused_taxonomy_terms_admin_settings($form_state) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_form_submit';
  return system_settings_form($form);
}

/**
 * Submit handler
 */
function custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $query = "
  SELECT taxonomy_term_data.tid AS tid
  FROM 
  {taxonomy_term_data} taxonomy_term_data
  LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} taxonomy_index ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = taxonomy_index.tid
  LEFT JOIN {node} node_taxonomy_index ON taxonomy_index.nid = node_taxonomy_index.nid
  LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} taxonomy_vocabulary ON taxonomy_term_data.vid = taxonomy_vocabulary.vid
  GROUP BY tid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT node_taxonomy_index.nid) = '0'";

  $tids = db_query($query)->fetchCol();

  foreach ($tids as $tid) {
    taxonomy_term_delete($tid);
  }
}
```

In your module folder make a folder named **delete_unused_taxonomy_terms** put the 3 files inside and install the module.

Then go to `admin/structure/delete_unused_taxonomy_terms` and click the button.

**Reference:**

- [How to delete true orphaned taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/99039/28275)
- [Create a Views that displays all unused taxonomy terms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/133564/28275)

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to inject code into your code base; Drush is your friend here.

Create a PHP script with the relevant PHP code that bulk deletes then execute the following in your Drupal environment:

```
drush php-script my_deletion_script.php
```